# Why do you need space between cd and .. in change directory command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am a newbie and would like to know if there is any way to eliminate the need for space between cd and .. in the change directory command i.e.
`cd..` instead of 
`cd ..`

Comment: why? ... reducing a command by one character has caused untold grief for users trying to unmount a disk volume

Comment: You can always set an alias: `alias cd..='cd ..'`